# SignalR: Reply to Web Forms client on same machine as web application originating request

Tags: asp.net, winforms, signalr

I'm looking for a way to support the following process:

1. Button is clicked in web application running on machine named PC1234.
2. Call is made to server (either the web server or an API on another server, it doesn't matter) to Do Something.
3. The server sends a notification to a Windows Forms client installed on PC1234 that the action is complete.

I've got the easy part working using SignalR. I can call a method on the web server and then send a notification with SignalR to ALL clients that the method has completed. The problem is notifying ONLY the client on the originating machine.

My initial plan was to include some unique identifying attribute of the machine with the call to the server which could then be used to direct the SignalR notification back to just that machine, but that doesn't seem to be possible.

An alternative idea was to have the call to the server include a unique reference and also update a file locally (i.e. a Cookie) with that reference, then have the client app poll the Cookie for new references and filter all SignalR messages received for that unique reference. This would be a bit clunky even if it worked, which it doesn't really, not least because I want this to work cross-browser, and different browsers store cookies in different places.

Ultimately this is to support printing locally and silently from a web application. The user selects a document in the web application, hits a print button, the request is sent to the server which retrieves the document from the database, saves it to a network share and sends a notification to a client app on the machine from which the print request was generated. The client app then prints the document from the network share and deletes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never found a way to do exactly what I described in my question, but I came up with an alternative which worked well enough.

In both my web application and my Windows Forms client, the user was logged in with the same Windows credentials. I was therefore able to have the server respond to the button click in the web application by broadcasting a SignalR message to all SignalR clients where the same user was logged in, using

```
Clients.User(userId).send(message)
```

See [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections) for more detailed examples and instructions.

In my Windows Forms client, I included code to track how many instances of the client were connected to the SignalR Hub with the same user credentials and code to handle the receipt of a SignalR message from the server when multiple client instances were connected with the same user details (in my case, this meant displaying a message saying something like "You've requested a print from the web application but you're logged in at multiple workstations. Do you want the document to print here?").